# Why isn't Google Maps always detailing the routes it suggests?

Tags: google-maps

Sometimes when using Google Maps, I get many details about the trip.
Sometimes, not at all.

Here's a screen grab showing Google Maps not displaying any details at all:

[image]

and here's an example of Google Maps actually displaying details:

[image]

How does one go from situation 1 to situation 2?

Now every once in a while I run into the situation in picture 1.
If I can reproduce it I will write the details here but I'm not sure how right now.